# Two blocks center positioning on storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have  a storyboard: http://prntscr.com/d15pmj 
I need it to be a: http://prntscr.com/d15qm5

How can I solve it?

Comment: I tried to drag and drop this elements, it was a fail)))

Comment: imageView.leadingToSuperview.constant == label.trailingToSuperview.constant --> centered views.

Comment: @FreeNickname Is it objective-c or swift? I programming on swift.

Comment: @ZolotukhinDmitriy it is a pseudocode. Setting equal constants for "imageView.Leading - superview.leading" and "label.trailing - superview.trailing" results in centered behaviour just as you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way: Embedded image and label in UIStacKView: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview
Constraints:
1) set horizontal container 0 to main view from stackview.
2) set top space to mainview form stackview
3) set left,right aligned from stack view to mainview. (optional)
4) set height to stackview

Answer (score 0):

Select both the image and label and click the button shown below

[image]

This will create a UIStackView. 
UIStackViews are basically views which are made of multiple views, so Interface builder treats them like any other views.

Comment: Caution: UIStackViews are iOS 9.0+ only.